# Find the limit of this large expression

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left\{(n+1)\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right\}^n$$ where $()$ and $\{\}$ are nothing except brackets.

I wrote the above expression as $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left\{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(n+\frac{1}{2^i}\right)\right\}^n$$

I can't apply L$'$Hopital's rule here. I'm stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

I honestly don't know what $(a)$ means and imho I guess $[a]$ means greatest integer less than or equal to $a$.

Comment: Isn't this clearly just $+\infty$? The expression is at least $(n^n)^n/n^2$ in size

Comment: A more interesting question is what happens when you replace "$1/n^2$" with $1/n^{n^2}$, since my computer believes the ratio tends to a definite limit (it only goes up to $n=15$ though since the numbers involved are so large0

Comment: I.e. I ask: are you sure you've transcribed the question correctly?

Comment: @FShrike im attaching the original figure and question

Comment: Right. Well, the question is mistaken. Any numerical check shows you this blows up very  quickly. Each multiplicand can be bounded below by $n$, so there is at least $n\times n\times n\times\cdots$ in the brackets, giving $(n^n)^n$

Comment: I agree with @FShrike. It looks like there is a typo in the given expression.

Comment: Please show us the link, we might be able to infer things from it.

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Just to clarify, does [a] mean floor function here and (a) means nothing(even i think so), also is this a question from fiitjee?

Comment: @Ercanayan I think so...and I found this on a telegram group...and if you don't mind would you tell your nationality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming (),{} mean nothing)

The question you have asked/been given is incorrect,

it is

$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left\{(n+1)\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right\}^n$$

when in fact it works when,

$$\boxed{L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n^2}}\left\{(n+1)\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right\}^n}$$

Also, let's define a limit,
$$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e}\tag1$$

$$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{an}\right)^n=e^{\frac{1}{a}}}\tag2$$

(1) is pretty well known result. But here's the proof anyways;

> (1) is a limit of the form $1^{\infty}$,
>
> Let,
>
> $$y= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
>
> Taking log on both sides,
>
> $$ln(y)= (n)\left(ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$
>
> $$ln(y)= \frac{ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
>
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ln(y)= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
> \frac{ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
>
> The limit now is converted to $\frac{0}{0}$ form, apply L-H rule to get the desired result.

---

> Extras of how the original question leads nowhere;
>
> $$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left\{n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)n\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)n\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2n}\right)\cdots
>  n\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n}\right)\right\}^n$$
>
> $$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left\{n^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2n}\right)^n\cdots
>  \left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n}\right)^n\right\}$$
>
> $$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{n}}}(n+1)^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2^2}\right)^n\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)^n\right\}$$

We have, $$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n^2}}\left\{(n+1)\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right\}^n$$

$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{n^{n}}(n+1)^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2^2}\right)^n\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)^n\right\}$$

Take $'n'$ common from every bracket,

$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{\frac{n^n}{n^{n}}\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2^2n}\right)^n\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n}\right)^n\right\}$$

$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2^2n}\right)^n\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n}\right)^n\right\}$$

Using (1) and (2),

$$\boxed{L=e.e^{\frac{1}{2}}.e^{\frac{1}{2^2}}\cdots=e^2}$$

Hence, $\lfloor a \rfloor =7$

Option (B) is correct (assuming it is floor function).